# Click event to fetch information from an SQL Database on Google Maps API V3

Tags: php, javascript, sql, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set up my google map in such a way that a person can click somewhere on a map, and then get information on that area based on the lat and lon of the area. All of these data are stored in an SQL database. Can someone start me off in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).  Google has tons of these examples, and simply listing them here isn't what SO was designed for.  I would suggest reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as [We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: havent tried anything yet, lost as to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

[Read about the SQL Geography type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895266%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)